# Is the tcp/ip optimal protocol for transfering large amount of data?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, ip

Tcp/ip is universal that suite for most of cases. And as a general solution it is not optimal for specific cases:
1) To transfer data over the continents with packet loss. (As example [Appera[1](http://asperasoft.com/whats-new/fasp-36-release/), for some cases it makes transfer faster 10x times.)
2) For gigabyte LAN with no packet loss. Here TCP/IP intruduce overhead with ACK and things that are for long dinstance and slow networks. I remember that read about some protocol for  gigabyte LAN that is significantly faster than TCP/IP.

The last one is interesting for backup the solution that should transfer huge amount of data. What do you know about alternative network data transfer protocols for windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing backup, I'm guessing #2 is the case you're concerned about.

TCP has several optimizations to address #2: sliding windows, windows scaling, and fast retransmit and recovery if congestion should occur. As long as the receiver's window is open, ACKs don't gate the effective bandwidth.

Since this question is on SO, I'm assuming programming is involved, so in implementing your receiving program you can keep window open by providing large buffers. Use the **bandwidth-delay product** in determining buffer size. You can dynamically compute this, or if your environment is stable, then you can use a static calculation.

Regarding windows protocols you have two choices. "In the box" and 3rd party. You can view in the box protocol by going to Control Panel, Network, Change Adpater settings (for your gigE adapter), Properties, Install, Protocol. On my 2008R2 system I only see Microsoft Virtual Switch Protocol, and Reliable Multicast Protocol. Neither would help unless you want to backup to multiple locations simultaneously (using multicast).

As far as 3rd party protocols go, that's really beyond the scope of SO. A couple of well chosen web searches will fill the bill for that.

And if you're going for absolute fastest speed and your backup source and target are in same broadcast domain, you can skip IP altogether and program at the MAC layer. You'll lose a lot of functionality, but if you do it well it'll be fast.